# Django REST Framework tutorial gives error, don't understand why

Tags: django, rest

I am working through the [full tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) in the [Django REST Framework website](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and am getting an error that doesn't make sense to me.

Here's the python session:

```
>>> from snippets.models import Snippet
>>> from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
>>> from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
>>> from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
>>> snippet = Snippet(code='foo = "bar"\n')
>>> snippet.save()
>>> snippet = Snippet(code='print "hello, world"\n')
>>> snippet.save()
>>> serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
>>> serializer.data
ReturnDict([('pk', 3), ('title', u''), ('code', u'print "hello, world"\n'), ('linenos', False), ('language', 'python'), ('style', 'friendly')])
>>> content = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
>>> content
'{"pk":3,"title":"","code":"print \\"hello, world\\"\\n","linenos":false,"language":"python","style":"friendly"}'
>>> from rest_framework.compat import BytesIO
>>> stream = BytesIO(content)
>>> data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
>>> serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
False
>>> serializer.errors
ReturnDict([('title', [u'This field may not be blank.'])])
>>>
```

Here's the relevant line from the serializer:

```
title = serializers.CharField(
    required=False,
    max_length=100,
    )
```

... and the relevant line from the model:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

The model and the serializer both allow empty values for 'title', but the error indicates that an empty value is not valid. Can someone explain why I might be seeing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this should do it for you :)

Take a look at the django rest framework

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py

specifically line 504 which has the following:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.allow_blank = kwargs.pop('allow_blank', False)
        max_length = kwargs.pop('max_length', None)
        min_length = kwargs.pop('min_length', None)
        super(CharField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if max_length is not None:
            message = self.error_messages['max_length'].format(max_length=max_length)
            self.validators.append(MaxLengthValidator(max_length, message=message))
        if min_length is not None:
            message = self.error_messages['min_length'].format(min_length=min_length)
            self.validators.append(MinLengthValidator(min_length, message=message))
```

<strike>Change your `serialization.CharField` as follows:</strike> Actually in reviewing the tutorial, is it possible you missed adding the `allow_blank` to another section that required it...  Specifically the `SnippetSerializer`

```
title = serializers.CharField(
    required=False,
    max_length=100,
    allow_blank=True,
    )
```

The validation being run is

```
def run_validation(self, data=empty):
        # Test for the empty string here so that it does not get validated,
        # and so that subclasses do not need to handle it explicitly
        # inside the `to_internal_value()` method.
        if data == '':
            if not self.allow_blank:
                self.fail('blank')
            return ''
        return super(CharField, self).run_validation(data)
```

Which as you can see checks to see if the CharField is blank, not if it is required or not.  It is the ONLY place that the blank error message is ever called.

Comment: Thanks! I see the tutorial has been updated since yesterday, apparently to fix this issue (and a couple others). It was changed after I started working on it, before I wrote this question, but I was still looking at the (just slightly) older version that didn't include the allow_blank parameter.